# Smallest mass possible to cause a neutron to orbit around a mass assuming there's no earth, sun, or moon

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, newtonian-gravity, orbital-motion

Just a hypothetical question...

Let's suppose we are in an universe like our own universe, except there's nothing in this universe except for the objects of our experience.  In other words, the force of gravity is zero everywhere except for the object in the experiment:

one neutron, and enough electrostatically neutral mass to hold said neutron in orbit around this mass, assuming the neutron has sufficient velocity to maintain a gravitational orbit about said mass.

what is the minimum amount of mass needed to keep the neutron in orbit around this mass.

Comment: so another words you could have two neutrons gravitationally orbiting around each other in a universe with nothing in it?  what would be radius of  their orbit, velocity, acceleration in that case?

Comment: now that would be interesting...  just to keep it simple, even in our own universe, there has to be at least one place where  space is perfectly flat and uncurved... maybe between two or more galaxies moving in just the right directions from each other... and in that place there could be two lonely neurons gravitationally orbiting around each other not under the influence of gravity from outside bodies because the space is locally flat and uncurved....

Comment: You better be quick! Your neutrons have a half-life of about 10 minutes & 11 seconds

Comment: in that case throw in an electron and call it a hydrogen atom instead.

Comment: I think you can actually orbit objects around each other at each distance... as long as there's no friction and you set the velocity correctly... because all object have a gravitational acceleration toward each other... for instance, if there were no atmosphere on earth you could orbit a satellite at a distance of the tallest mountain on Earth...it would just need a larger velocity to keep it in orbit...

Comment: I deleted my wrong comments and wrote an answer

Comment: I guess this is why they have trouble unifying gravity with particle forces... Newtonian gravity is just absurd on the small scale approaching an atom...

Answer (score 1):

The answer is any mass. The speed $v$ of a circular orbit between the two particles of the same mass is $v=\sqrt{Gm/2R}$. You can have an orbit of any desired radius. $v$ will be slow because $m$ is very small. You can increase it by reducing the distance as much as you want.

Answer (score 0):

According to Newton:

$a = \frac{GM}{r^2}$

a = "planet's" acceleration... for Earth a=9.8 meters/second^2 on the surface.

M = mass of "planet" = 1 atomic mass unit for a neutron =  $1.6603 \times 10^{-27}~\text{kilograms}$

r = radius from the planet center  = let's pick 1 centimeter just as an example.

G = the universal gravitational constant = $6.6726 \times 10^{-11} (N~m^2)/kg^2$

That's means for a neutron acting as a "planet" around which another neutron mass orbits at 1 cm... the other neutron is accelerating towards the neutron "planet" at a gravitational acceleration of:

$a = 1.1078 \times 10^{-33}~\text{meter/second}^2$

---

Example 2:

if we choose r = 120 pm, the width of a hydrogen atom...
and keep the same mass of $M=1~\text{amu}$, then:

$a = 7.693 \times 10^{-18} ~\text{meter/second}^2$

---

so I guess it would take an absurdly long time for one neutron to orbit another neutron by gravity alone.... and the angular velocity would be miniscule as well... i would look like its not even moving... so this might be one where we let $\lim \limits_{t \to \infty}$

Comment: Please note that the old atomic mass unit amu isn‘t used in physics anymore since 1960, and that’s not the mass of a neutron anyway.

Comment: The 1 cm you used is actually a huge distance considering how small a neutron is. You should work out your problem for r = 1 nm and see what you get.

Comment: I tried it for the width of a hydrogen atom...   I just thought it was interesting that it works for any distances if your universe is empty... maybe this is every javascript gravity simulation ever written...